# UISegmentedControl navigation problem in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have made a segment control.

In that there is three segments..

Now I have used a single table in which when I select different segments..different data appears accordingly in the rows of that table..

Now my problem ...

When I select segment 1...it should navigate to the FirstViewController...when I select row from appeared table

When I select segment 2...it should navigate to the SecondViewController...when I select row from appeared table

When I select segment 3...it should navigate to the ThirdViewController...when I select row from appeared table

where FirstViewController,SecondViewController,ThirdViewController are simple viewControllers with some Image

How to do this?

Comment: "the particular view 1" -- which particular view one? You need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done..

What I did..I did store the value of which segmented control is selected..

then according to the selected segment control ..I made the switch case in row did select..

rathodrc

Comment: @Parth..hehe...bhai..boy has learned..boy has learned..yeah in Ahmedabad..and you?? Baroda??

Answer (score 0):

In your tableview delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

check the selected index of the segment control using `segmentcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex`. Depending upon this push whatever viewcontroller you require.